# Root, children and multiple locks

Tags: asynchronous, locking, distributed

Simplified structure of what I have is:

- some single roots
- each root has many (e.g. 100s) of children

User may update the root information, and no other operation on children should be allowed (because root change may affect all of them).

Also, user may operate on children (if root is not in use, of course). For example, user may change 2 children in the same time, and this is allowed, since each children is independent.

I need locks in this structure in order to be sure there are no corruptions:

- when children is in use, lock the children. This will not allow two operations on the same children in same time.
- when root is in use, lock root AND *all* the children. This will forbid the operations on any children while root is updated.

What bothers me here is the need to lock *all* the children - in a distributed system that means sending that many requests to distributed lock.

Is there any better solution I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two things. First, it's safe for multiple threads to read from a node at the same time, as long as nobody is writing to it. Second, the child nodes can be viewed as their own roots of smaller trees, so the same algorithm/solution may be applied to all nodes except leaf nodes. The first one is most important. Here's how you could do this:

**Use a read/write mutex on all nodes in the tree.** This allows any number of processes to concurrently read, or a single process to write to a node at any time.

**To read:**

1. read-lock node and all parents all the way up to root.
2. read.
3. release all read-locks.

**To write:**

1. write-lock the least-upper-bound of the nodes you want to modify. If you're modifying a node (and possibly any of its children), write-lock that node.
2. do your modifications
3. release the write-lock

This means two siblings may be modified concurrently, and that any number of reads may execute concurrently. However, the cost of reading is that you need to grab O(log100(tree_height)) read-locks, for a tree with roughly 100 children at each level. It's unlikely to be a real problem, unless your tree is huge, with extremely many reads and writes to the same leaf node.

This assumes that no child may modify its parent.